# Going from Scrum to Kanban near "release"

Tags: agile, scrum, kanban

I am working as Scrum Master on a large software project. We are currently running Scrum.
We have about one month left in the development phase before we are supposed to end our implementation phase.

I am strongly considering switching to Kanban (Or GTD) for the last couple of weeks due to:

1. We have an absolute deadline
2. It is very hard to plan two (or one) week ahead now that we are this close to the end. The agenda, priority and outstanding tasks changes almost each day. We daily find new tasks we must remember to do before we can say our development phase is finished.
3. Kanban let me easier identfiy which tasks are waiting for reponse, which tasks are waiting for verification etc.

Anybody have experiences with this? Is this a good idea?

Our sprints are not entirely pontensial shippable increments (I know they should have been, but thats not what I want to discuss here)

Comment: You dont fail scrum even though you adapt it, inspect and adapt is the key here. But ofcourse in an ideal world  and in other settings we would defenitely change this, but I have been working as a scrum master in several companies for the last 6 years working with scrum teams for 5-20 person (over several teams), so please.....

Comment: Kanban won't deal well with the absolute deadline - that's not really what its about. Pragmatically you'll never - not ever - get to the end of the list, however what you're really talking about is taking the visualization, prioritization and - presumably - WIP limit elements more than anything else and yes, that should help.

Comment: Good answear Murph, regading the absolute deadline, I agree Kanban is not the key. Thats why I added the GTD in comment as we probably gonna need a somewhat Kanban inspired setup limiting WIP, vizualising workflow and obstacles and prioritizing tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I can be considered a Kanban proponent I would think twice before making such move.

On one side:

- Kanban deals very neatly with rapidly changing task priorities. It is a good answer for environments where classic time-boxed approach, here: Scrum, doesn't work very well.
- Introducing simple Kanban system doesn't require much effort.
- Kanban itself isn't an approach to software development and/or project management and should be put on the top of something. However, it seems that you already have this "something" as, at the moment, you have your project organized.

On the other hand:

- Adding new tool to your toolbox always adds some hassle and, since you are at the end of the project, it may not be such a good idea to add the hassle now.
- Kanban, as pretty much any other tool, will give you value if and only if you get team buy-in before introducing it. I mean Kanban board is useless unless it is updated by everyone in the team regularly.
- If you are fluent with what you do, namely following Scrum, resigning from a part of it, namely time-boxing, may have a negative impact on team's productivity. At the same time it'll take some time before you get familiar with a new method, so there can be a question when you're going to get value of switching to other method.

All in all, I would definitely consider Kanban to such work as it gives you pretty good visibility and high flexibility in a situation where priorities are changing all the time. However, I wouldn't say that, in your case, it is a sure-shot decision. If you planned for it in a bit longer perspective it would be a no-brainer to try Kanban.

Personally, I'd probably try anyway and treat it as an experiment. If it works you keep doing it. If it doesn't you retreat back to what you are good at and eventually try Kanban in another project with a bit more preparation.